# ofstream not creating file (Node.js addon)

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I am attempting to create an [addon for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) that (among other things) writes content to a file inside my C++ class using `ofstream`.

```
std::ofstream license_file;

std::string fileContent(*NanAsciiString(args[0]));

license_file.open(PATH);

//file doesn't yet exist, so create it
if(!license_file) {
    printf("ERROR: %s (%s)\n", strerror(errno), PATH);
}

license_file <<  fileContent;
license_file.close();
```

This works fine if `PATH` is set to the same directory as my Node.js code (e.g. `./license.txt`).

**However, `ofstream` fails to open/create the file in question if it is located anywhere else. For example, using `~/license.txt` does not work (note: I'm running OSX).**

The error reported is always `No such file or directory` -- even after I physically create `~/license.txt`.

Any ideas why this works in one directory but not others? If it were a permissions issue I would expect a different error message.

For the record, I've seen about 20 other SO questions about "ofstream fails to create file" but passing additional flags into `open()` has no effect. I have a feeling this is somehow related to running inside Node/V8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to find out the user directory in a different way than using `~`.

Comment: Gah, yes I have to get the user's home directory using `getpwuid(getuid())` and then parse `pw_dir` from the structure.